# Произведение элементов массива за О(n)

Tags: алгоритм

Дан массив из `array[N]` элементов (целых чисел). Предложите линейный (время `О(n)`) алгоритм, который сформирует на выходе такой массив, что `out[i]` будет равен произведению всех элементов `array[N]`, за исключением `array[i]`, при этом запрещается использовать оператор деления.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сначала считаем произведение элементов слева. Затем справа. Код на C:

```
int t = 1; 
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { 
    out[i] = t; 
    t *= array[i]; 
}

t = 1; 
for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i) { 
    out[i] *= t; 
    t *= array[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Сначала заполним out так, чтобы в out[i] хранилось произведение всех элементов array от (i + 1)-го  до последнего. Это можно сделать за O(n) пробежавшись по массиву array с конца.
Затем пробегаемся сначала, сохраняя число before - произведение всех элементов array лежащих до текущего. after - произведение всех элементов array лежащих после текущего, получаем из out[i + 1]. Ответом для текущего элемента является after * before. Реализация на python:

```
array = [i for i in xrange(1, 10)]
n = len(array)
out = [v for v in array]
for i in xrange(n - 2, -1):
    out[i] *= out[i + 1]

before = out[0]
out[0] = out[1]
for i in xrange(1, n - 1):
   after = out[i + 1]
   out[i] = after * before
   before *= array[i]
out[n - 1] = before
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr1 = new int[N];
arr1[0] = 1
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    arr1[i] = arr1[i - 1] * array[i - 1];

arr2 = new int[N];
arr2[N - 1] = 1
for(int i = N - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    arr2[i] = arr2[i + 1] * array[i + 1];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    out[i] = arr1[i] * arr2[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Прикольный метод с суффиксами и префиксами (`novgosh`). Храним в одном массиве суффиксы в другом префиксы, а дальше всё просто. Реализация на `pascal`.

```
var a,suf,pref,out:array[0..1000] of longint;
    i,n:integer;

begin

 {считываем размер массива}

 writeln('n='); readln(n);

 {считываем сам массив}

 for i:=1 to n do        
  read(a[i]);

 pref[0]:=1;
 suf[n+1]:=1;

 {вычисляем префикс}

 for i:=1 to n do                 
  pref[i]:=a[i]*pref[i-1];

 {вычисляем суффикс}

 for i:=n downto 1 do            
  suf[i]:=a[i]*suf[i+1];

 {вычисляем сам массив out}

 for i:=1 to n do                
  out[i]:=pref[i-1]*suf[i+1];

 {выводим массив out}  
 for i:=1 to n do               
  write(out[i],' ');

 readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Я как всегда приведу оригинальное решение:

```
int mul=1;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) mul*=array[i];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) out[i]=mul*pow(array[i], -1); //Здесь нет оператора деления!
```

Comment: ахаха, хитро

Answer (score 0):

Сначала посчитать произведения на всех префиксах, потом на всех суффиксах (За `O(n)` просто циклом `suf[i] = i ? suf[i - 1] * array[i] : array[i]`). После чего `out[i]` - это произведение  префикса, оканчивающегося слева, на суффикс, начинающийся справа.

Comment: @NovGosh, если не сложно, покажите конкретный код!

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт на с#:

```
        // объявление переменных
        int p = 1;
        int n;

        // определение размера массивов
        Console.Write("Введите N ");
        try
        {
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите целое число!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        // объявление массива array
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int[] out_array = new int[n];

        // заполнение массива array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i + 1;
        }

        // заполнение массива out_array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                    p *= array[j];
            }
            out_array[i] = p;
            p = 1;
        }

        // вывод на экран массива out_array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("out_array[{0}] = {1}" , i, out_array[i]);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: это O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

```
int m = 3; //индекс исключения
int[] a; //наш массив
int s = 1; //произведение
a = new int[5];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
a[4] = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    s *= a[i];
}
for (int i = m+1; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    s *= a[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понял требуемую задачу, но всё же.

```
$array = array(1, 5, 6, 2, 9, 10, 15, 2, 7, 31); // массив 
$out = array();
$i = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(!$out[$i]) $out[$i] = 1;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) if($i != $key) $out[$i] *= $value;
};
echo $out[1]; // выведет произведение всех элементов массива, но не умножая на $array[1], результат 7030800
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = array[i]
array[i] = 1
out[i] = ... // перемножаем элементы
array[i] = x
```

Comment: O(n^2), нет?